# Debug Motorola Triumph

Tags: android, debugging, adb, motorola

I have installed the latest Motorola USB drivers which include support for the Triumph.

When I plug in my phone, "adb devices" does not list my phone.

My device manager shows my device under Phone as well as Disk Drive.  Both use the WPD FileSystem Volume Driver and refuse to let me update the driver by pointing the motorola drivers in Program Files.  It continues to tell me that "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently in just about the exact same predicament =/

I have some possible avenues that we could both share:

1. Idk if you were able to find a phone number for Motorola (American that is) but i finally found one

   ```
   Motorola Mobility, Inc.
   600 North U.S. Highway 45
   Libertyville, Illinois 60048 USA
   Telephone: +1 847 523 5000
   ```
2. [Here](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Triumph-as-a-dev-phone/m-p/17188/message-uid/17188/highlight/true#U17188) is a link to yet ANOTHER programmer having the same prob as us =/, but he got it figured out using the steps he posted there

Also there is live support chat [here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_launch/).

If you find a solution to this problem, please, please, please let me know =) And i will do the same for you if i get it figured out soon.

Edit:

Nevermind, i got mine to work just fine =)

Heres what i did:

1. Used [USBDeview](http://download.cnet.com/USBDeview/3000-2094_4-10614190.html) to uninstall all previously failed attempts at drivers lol
   NOTE: You will have to run USBDeview as an Administrator(right click, select Run as administrator)
2. In the device manager, after uninstalling all the others, right click on what pops up for the device, click update driver, browse for your own, than from there it was a series of selecting from lists, but the key thing here is to remember that eclipse debugs programs on external devices using the adb interface, which should be a pre loaded option in said select lists =)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for this!  After much cursing, what finally worked for me was: uninstalling the "USB Mass Storage Device" and its sub-items "Android SCSI CD-ROM V001 USB Device" and "Qualcomm Mass Storage USB Device" and then scanning for hardware changes in Device Manager (Windows 7 for what it's worth). No reboot or even disconnecting of the phone was needed!  You know you're in good shape when the device is detected as a "USB Composite Device" containing "ADB Interface"!

Comment: Love you guys. Wouldn't have been able to do this without you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled debug mode for your phone? This can be done via settings->application settings->development->USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had a problem with adb recognizing my devices I've managed to fix it by adding a reference to it in my .android/adb_usb.ini file.

I only run Linux/OS X at home and I don't want to try and blindly describe how to do it on Windows from memory, but they discuss it here http://android.modaco.com/topic/294799-adb-windows-7-and-the-pulse-tutorial/

And google gives the USB Vendor ID's here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html .

On my linux box I added:

```
0x0489
```

To my adb_usb.ini (using the Foxconn ID which on linux you can find directly via lsusb, I think you could use devcon on Windows to find it) and it shows up on my device list.

Answer (score 0):

Just because this link hasn't been dropped in any answers (and I always find myself looking for it), [here](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/USB_Drivers/) are the manufacturer's development drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I have a Moto Triumph and Win7 x64...

Turn on Unknown Sources, USB Debugging

Install Motorola USB development driver. Unfortunately, Motorola broke the old driver URL, as well as many development forum URL's. Fortunately, Softpedia has copies of the installer. Grab the [32 bit](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Drivers/Motorola-Handset-USB-Driver-for-Windows-32-bit-38123.shtml) or [64 bit](http://handheld.softpedia.com/progDownload/Motorola-Handset-USB-Driver-for-Windows-64-bit-Download-38124.html) version depending on your OS.

Plug in your phone by USB

Open Device Manager

View hidden devices

Uninstall default drivers (Disk Drives\Qualcomm USB, DVD\CD\Android SCSI CD-ROM, Portable Devices\F:)

Action > scan for hardware changes, or Disconnect/reconnect phone

Repeat till ADB appears (probably w/ a yellow icon indicating it's not fully installed)

Right-click ADB > update driver > browse my computer for driver > pick from a list > Motorola > Android Sooner ADB (the first entry)

Accept security warning

Done. If it worked properly, you can now view your device using adb devices.